# 4x 2:1 Multiplexer with multiple select lines. Does that exist?

Tags: digital-logic, multiplexer, remote-control

I have been checking different supplier websites, and can't seem to find what I am looking for so I am wondering if it even exists or not.

I am looking for a 4x 2:1 MUX IC with 4 select lines. I am trying to create a design for remote control that doesn't require a microcontroller by daisy chaining 2:1's together as shown in the picture below. The digital inputs represent button presses on my RC. I have 8 buttons to work with on my transceiver module and by using two of the MUX's I am trying to get up to 16.

I looked into using 4:1's but I would be leaving one input line empty because I cannot use the case when SEL1 = 1 and SEL2 = 1 because I am daisy chaining them together.

If this isn't the best route to take, can you please share what you might do?

[image: Simulation Example of what I am trying to do]

Comment: MC140xx analog muxes; with ina/inb/out/select X 4, that's 16 pins; probably not; but a triple, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ADG734, 4 x 1:2 switch with 4 control lines
Available at Digikey.com

> 4 Circuit IC Switch 2:1, 4.5Ohm, 20-TSSOP
>
> 1.8 V to 5.5 V Single Supply
>
> or 2.5 V Dual Supply
>
> 2.5  On Resistance
>
> 0.5  On Resistance Flatness
>
> 100 pA Leakage Currents
>
> 19 ns Switching Times

https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADG733_734.pdf

MAX333 is another, less expensive choice, also at Digikey. Appears to need higher power supply (+/-5V, or 0/10V)

https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX333.pdf

Comment: Thank you! I think I will give the ADG734 a try.